# Is there a better way of writing?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a better way of writing? I think its so surplus.

```
let {
        recruitmentType,
        positionName,
        positionType,
        labels,
        workAddressId,
        positionBrightPoint,
        positionDesc,
        department,
        jobNature,
        workYear,
        education,
        salary,
        isSchoolPosition
      } = this.data;
      windows.setStorage('saveReleaseJob', {
        recruitmentType,
        positionName,
        positionType,
        labels,
        workAddressId,
        positionBrightPoint,
        positionDesc,
        department,
        jobNature,
        workYear,
        education,
        salary,
        isSchoolPosition
      })
```

Comment: how your `this.data` looks like ?

Comment: Why not just `windows.setStorage('saveReleaseJob', this.data)`?

Comment: @Satpal there may be other keys which are not needed to store on `saveReleaseJob`, even though i am not sure, if there aren't any then the posted thing by OP doesn't makes any sense at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a function for getting a subset of the wanted properties.

```js
const getOnly = (object, keys) => Object.assign({}, ...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: object[k] })));

var object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 },
    keys = ['a', 'b'],
    subset = getOnly(object, keys);

console.log(subset);
```

With upcoming `Object.fromEntries`

```js
const getOnly = (object, keys) => Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, object[k]]));

var object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 },
    keys = ['a', 'b'],
    subset = getOnly(object, keys);

console.log(subset);
```